# storing values in variable and print them using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Is it possible to do something like this? I'm new to this so don't know!

```
//row 1 in mysql array
$var = "hello"; 
$id = 1; 

//row 2 in mysql array
$var = "bye";
$id = 2;

//Closing while loop

//Is the following possible?
echo $var1; //outputs "hello"
echo $var2; //outputs "bye"
```

Comment: I think you need to learn a bit more about php.

Comment: You have incorrect syntax at the end, it should be `echo $var1; echo $var2;` but still, since `var1` and `var2` haven't been defined, this isn't possible to do it like this. You could define `var` and `id` as arrays and then access them using `var[0]` `var[1]` etc.

Comment: The way you write your `$echo` means it's a variable the proper syntax is `echo $yourvar/string`.

Comment: Why will it be useful?

Comment: Woops my bad, just tired ^^ How do I save them in arrays? @JonathonHenderson.

Comment: This is just an simple example. My code contains hundreds of rows in my mysql array. Saving them each by them self will take to long time. Therefore I need to save them in the while loop like data1, data2 etc @silentboy

Comment: Then, use PHP array. whats problem with that?

Comment: I'll write an answer as an example for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention MySQL. So a more complete example of what you want to achieve would be:

```
$var = array();
$id  = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $var[] = $row['text']; // don't know how the column is named
    $id[]  = $row['id'];
}

echo $row[0]; // hello
echo $row[1]; // bye
```

With a looping variable `i`:

```
$var = array();
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $var[$i] = $row['text']; // don't know how the column is named
    $i++;
}

echo $row[1]; // hello
echo $row[2]; // bye
```

Comment: Lets say i dont have the id in mysql. just like id = 0 and in while loop id++; How do I put it in array then? @Reeno

Comment: Even better: $var[$row['id']] = $row['text']; then he can look up $var[$id]

Comment: @PeterB if you do: $var[] = $row['text']; it will automatically set the index. First element will be in $var[0], the second in $var[1] etcetera

Comment: @PeterP I added an example with the variable `i`. But also works as Jeroen described (my first example)

Answer (score 3):

Not like you want, you can use an array though:

```
$var[1] = "hello";
$var[2] = "bye";

echo $var[1];
echo $var[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do so

```
$id = 1; 
$var[$id] = "hello";
$id = 2;
$var[$id] = "bye";
echo $var['1']; 
echo $var['2']; 
// or
echo $var[$id];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Define them both as arrays
$var = array();
$id = array();

// In your loop
$var[] = "hello";
$id[] = 1;

// Next iteration
$var[] = "bye";
$id[] = 2;

// Printing them out
echo $var[0]; // prints out "hello"
echo $var[1]; // prints out "bye"
```

Using arrays^^

Alternatively:

```
$rows = array();

// In your loop
$rows[] = array("id" => 1, "var" => "hello");

// Next iteration
$rows[] = array("id" => 2, "var" => "bye");

// Print them out
echo $rows[0]["var"]; // Prints hello
echo $rows[1]["var"]; // Prints bye
```